# Applied Example of Coriolis Force/ Effect for an Object Moving around Earth

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, newtonian-gravity, reference-frames, coriolis-effect

There are very few examples on the Internet about how to calculate the Coriolis Force of an object moving around Earth.

Could you give me your feedback about how I proceeded ?

---

The Coriolis Force is given by

$$\overrightarrow{F_c} = 2m (\overrightarrow{v} \times \overrightarrow{\omega}) $$

So the important point is that we are dealing with vectors, so we need to use an appropriate coordinate system. We are given this Coordinate System :

[image]

We need the mass, the velocity, the direction and the latitude of the object that travels around the planet. So for example we have an object with a mass of $ m = 4.09 \cdot 10^5$ kg traveling at a speed of $ v = 300 \frac{km}{h} = \frac{300}{3.6} \frac{m}{s}$, in direction south, and a latitude of $53.55°N$.

We will also need the value of the angular velocity $\omega$ of Earth Rotation wich is $\frac{2\pi}{24\cdot 60 \cdot 60} \frac{\text{rad}}{s}$

Now, the most important point is to get the vectors right. Then we simply need to compute the cross product, plug in the values, and we are done.

Knowing the object moves south, and by looking at our coordinate system, we get : $\overrightarrow{v} = (0,-v,0)$. And for $\overrightarrow{\omega} = (0, \omega \cdot \cos\phi, \omega \cdot \sin\phi)$.

We now evaluate the Cross Product and get $\overrightarrow{v} \times \overrightarrow{\omega} = (-v \cdot \omega \cdot \sin\phi, 
 0, 0)$.

The angle $\phi$ is equal to the latitude, so in our case $\phi = 53.55° = 0.935$ radians.

We now simply need to plug in all numbers. We get (units in Newtons)

$$\overrightarrow{F_c} = 2m (\overrightarrow{v} \times \overrightarrow{\omega}) = 2m(-v \cdot \omega \cdot \sin\phi, 
 0, 0) = (-4000, 0,0) $$

Looking at the Coordinate System, we can see that the Coriolis Force points toward west when the object moves in direction south. The direction could also quickly be obtained with the right hand rule.

Is this correct ?

Thank you for your feedback !

---

EDIT : **Special Case at the Equator**

For an object at the Equator, the methodology above is the same. At the Equator, Latitude is zero so $\phi = 0$, $\sin \phi = 0 $ and $\cos \phi = 1$.

So the angular velocity vector is $$\overrightarrow{\omega} = (0, \omega \cdot 1, \omega \cdot 0) = (0, \omega, 0)$$

If the object moves **North** or **South** at the Equator, the Coriolis Force is zero because $$\overrightarrow{v} = (0,\pm v,0)$$ and $$ \overrightarrow{v} \times \overrightarrow{\omega} = (0,0,0)$$

However, if the object moves **West** or **East** at the Equator, we have $$\overrightarrow{v} = (\pm v,0,0)$$ and $$ \overrightarrow{v} \times \overrightarrow{\omega} = (0, \mp v\cdot \omega \cdot \sin\phi,\pm v\cdot \omega \cdot \cos\phi) = (0, \mp v\cdot \omega \cdot \sin0,\pm v\cdot \omega \cdot \cos0) = (0,0,\pm v\cdot \omega)$$

So we can see that an object moving West at the Equator has a Coriolis Force pointing inside Earth, and moving East pointing toward outer space.

The Eötvös Effect is closely related, see more on Wikipedia : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E%C3%B6tv%C3%B6s_effect

---

I hope I made no mistake. Feel free to comment if anything is unclear ! Thanks for your feedback !

Comment: your calculation is correct. with those components of the Coriolis Force, you  can discuss different cases
\begin{align*}
 &\vec{F}_c=-2\,m\,(\vec{\omega}\times\vec{v})=2\,m\,
 \left[ \begin {array}{c} \sin \left(\varphi\right) \omega\,v_{{
y}}\\ -\sin \left(\varphi\right) \omega\,v_{{x
}}\\ \cos \left(\varphi\right) \omega\,v_{{x}}
\end {array} \right]
\end{align*}

Comment: @Eli Thanks a lot ! Feel free to post your comment as an answer. I don't think someone else is likely to answer, so I would accept your answer

Comment: @JEB Feel free to post an answer if you want. I would accept your answer, so the question doesn't appear in the unanswered questions anymore